# Is there a css3 animations equivalent of fx off?

Tags: css, animation

Is there an equivalent for...

```
$.fx.off = true;
```

...in the world of pure css animations/transitions?

I'm working on a site that has tons of entry animations using both jquery and css, such that every time I change something and reload the page I'm stuck having to wait ten seconds for the entry anims to complete. It's pretty tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make all animations and transitions hop to the last frame instantly once started, and also removes the delays:

```
* {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;
    animation-duration: 0s !important;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s !important;
    animation-delay: 0s !important;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s !important;
    transition-duration: 0s !important;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s !important;
    transition-delay: 0s !important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ejInuMA/1/edit)

To apply it programmatically, change the selector to `.no-anim *` and apply the `no-anim` class to the `<html>` (or another containing element). [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ejInuMA/2/edit)

I haven't tested this throughout yet, but it seems to work nicely for simple use cases at least. Feel free to adapt it to your needs, comment and improve.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of globally turning off CSS animations, however you could use a link to simulate animations being 'turned off':

Assuming your animations are bound normally:

```
body .elementClassName {
    transition: propertyName 10s linear;
}

body:target .elementClassName {
    transition: none;
    transition: propertyName 0 linear;
}
```

This way, assuming that your `body` element has an `id` (for example `<body id="bodyElementID">`), if the page is loaded normally, at `http://example.com/page.html` transitions will occur, however if the page is loaded as: `http://example.com/page.html#bodyElementID` the transitions will not occur.

This is, without a demonstration of your real HTML a very generic overview of the possibility, but it's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to universally turn off CSS animations.

If you want to do something like this, place the animation pieces in a separate CSS class:

```
.AnimationOfWhatever {
    -webkit-animation: entryAnimation 10s;
    -moz-animation: entryAnimation 10s;
    -o-animation: entryAnimation 10s;
    -ms-animation: entryAnimation 10s;
    animation: entryAnimation 10s;
}
```

and apply that class on your first load via jQuery (since you mentioned jQuery).

```
$('.ElementToAnimate').one('load',function(){
    $(this).addClass('AnimationOfWhatever');
});
```

This will only load the animation once. If you want to only add that class once, create localStorage value and check that value:

```
$(function(){
    if(localStorage['loaded'] === undefined){
        localStorage['loaded'] = 'true';
    }

    $('.ElementToAnimate').on('load',function(){
        if(!JSON.parse(localStorage['loaded'])){
            $(this).addClass('AnimationOfWhatever');
        }
    });
});
```

This will only run the animation once across all pages.